# GL_INVALID_ENUM right after context initialization

Tags: c++, opengl

I am getting GL_INVALID_ENUM code when calling glGetError right after glew init has finished and before any other gl command was called.I am setting OpenGL 4.2 CORE ,forward compatible.Using GLFW for window/input and GLEW for gl context all this running on Windows 7 64bit.My graphic card is GeForce 550GT which has the latest drivers with OpenGL 4.2.Another strange thing is that I was using glDrawElements() which worked fine.But then I tried glDrawArrays(), which I needed for some specific task, and it didn't work at all.I double rechecked all the gl syntax ,buffer creations shaders etc.Nothing.I do get GL_INVALID_OPERATION when calling glDrawArrays() and I have no Idea why.All this work is a mini render engine but currently the pipeline is really simple so I can't understand what can be the problem.Here is how I initialize the context and window:

```
 void Engine::InitWithGLFW(){


    if(!glfwInit()){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT,GL_TRUE);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES,0);
    glfwDisable( GLFW_AUTO_POLL_EVENTS );

 #ifdef DEBUG
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);
 #endif

    if(!glfwOpenWindow(_width,_height,8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8,GLFW_WINDOW)){
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwSetWindowTitle("XDEngine V-1.0");
    InitGlew();



}

void  Engine::InitGlew(){
    glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit(); 

    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));

    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Status: Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));

    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(true);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDepthRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(Reshape);
}
```

And this is the render loop for glDrawArrays():

```
     void Draw(){
            _material->Draw();///activate shader program
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            _material->PostDraw();  //deactivate shader program

   }
```

As I said , all the buffers and shader programs are initialized ok.
UPDATE:
Ok , I found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857335/opengl-glgeterror-returns-invalid-enum-after-call-to-glewinit?rq=1) for the first issue :

Seems like GL_INVALID_ENUM  may happen after GlewInit and it is not supposed to screw the rendering.So I am left with the second problem...

### UPDATE1:

I found the workaround for GL_INVALID_ENUM  when calling glDrawArrays() with VBO.If I pack the VBO into VAO The error disappears and I get the rendering working.Does it mean that in forward compatible core profile we can't draw using VBO directly?Never seen anything related to it in the official docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Vertex array objects are not optional](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Causes_of_rendering_failure) in the core profile. The `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error is probably coming from somewhere else; you should be getting `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. Remember: OpenGL errors are buffered, so you have to keep fetching GL errors until you come back with `GL_NO_ERROR`.

> glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT,GL_TRUE);

Please stop doing this. Forward compatibility is [virtually meaningless](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts#Forward_compatibility) in a core profile.

Comment: "Vertex array objects are not optional in the core profile" -that's what I wanted to hear :)