# GL Error 1280 when enabling depth test

Tags: c++, opengl, error-handling

I'm having some problems with an opengl application I'm writing.

```
GLenum err = 0;
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
err = glGetError();
if ( err != GL_NO_ERROR )
    printf( "Error: %s\n",glewGetErrorString( err ) );
```

The above code prints out unknown error to the console, and when I step through it, I get the 1280 code. I've checked the khronos page for glEnable and the enum is there, so why would this cause an issue?
I've looked up the error code and it's for an invalid enum, but how can this be?

Comment: Why do you call it "error 1280", when you printed out the actual string name of the error?

Comment: Because glewGetErrorString outputs "unknown error". I had to look it up via the khronos site.

Comment: ... Oh! I looked up `glewGetErrorString`. It's not for getting OpenGL errors. It's for getting the errors from *GLEW*, such as those returned by `glewInit`.

Comment: That makes sense, however, it still doesn't explain the invalid enum error code which glGetError() returns.

Comment: Can you confirm you're calling glEnable on the thread with the OpenGL context?

Comment: It's a single threaded application, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Error 0x500/1280 means `GL_INVALID_ENUM`, which means one of the enumerators in the function call is not allowed. Obviously, that should not happen with `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, which has been allowed in `glEnable` since OpenGL 1.0. The following are all of the possible reasons why this might happen:

1. The error is coming from some other function. Be sure you're removed all errors from the queue before making this call. You say you already tried that; I'm just being comprehensive.
2. Your OpenGL Loading Library is faulty. Perhaps it has given the wrong value to `GL_DEPTH_TEST`. The value of `GL_DEPTH_TEST` should be 0x0B71. Alternatively, it may have put the wrong function in `glEnable`. To test this, you could debug into your library's initialization function, or you could use [glIntercept](https://github.com/dtrebilco/glintercept) or a similar tool to see exactly what function is being called.
3. Driver bug. To test this, try putting this enable (with error checking) in different places in your code. Where does it error and where does it not?

Comment: By moving the glEnable code to before glewInit(), I eliminated the error. However, the problem which led to my discovery of that error is still there: The depth buffer is not being written to.

Comment: @IanYoung: You can't move the `glEnable` to before glewInit; until GLEW has been initialized, that function doesn't exist.

Comment: Well it seems to be working as it was before, but without the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the error came from the `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` call ?

You may try this:

```
PrintErrors();               // Test for previous error
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
PrintErrors();

...

void PrintError() {
    GLenum err;
    for(;;) {
        err = glGetError();
        if (err == GL_NO_ERROR) break;
        printf("Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. That code sample was just a small part of my rendering set up code. I error check after each gl call. all prior getError calls return GL_NO_ERROR.

I'll add that I found this error while searching for a reason my rendering wasn't working at all. Upon using Nvidia Nsight, and examining the depth buffer, nothing had been written to it, which led me to error check the depth test set up in particular.

Comment: Have you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857335/opengl-glgeterror-returns-invalid-enum-after-call-to-glewinit ?

Comment: I had considered that, which is why I call glGetError() after glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; to clear the error queue. It's definitely the glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this error comes from `glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST )`;

**The code `1280` means `GL_INVALID_ENUM`;**

I've encountered this error before. In my situation, I passed a `renderer_program` to `glEnable` method by mistake. After passing a correct enum to the method, OpenGL tells no errors.

So, maybe you need to focus on other parts of your code.